# How to use Cache.NoSlidingExpiration in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to migrate ASP.NET webforms to .NET Core Razor pages.

And I need help find the correct syntax of `Cache.NoSlidingExpiration` in .NET Core. Could someone please assist me here?

I tried to use `IMemoryCache`, but it did not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6v47.png)

Comment: One possible way is you set a very long sliding expiration and repeatedly accessed it, which will make the cache item never expire. A cached item set with only a sliding expiration is at risk of never expiring. If the cached item is repeatedly accessed within the sliding expiration interval, the item never expires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the expiration to a very long time from now:

```
var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions { AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.MaxValue};
_memoryCache.Set(key, secret, cacheEntryOptions);
```